# Using my own sql server for the program authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

When I create a new mvc project, VS creates for me models and controllers to let me log in my application.

I'd like to connect this app to a sql server, and use this sql server for the app authentication.

In the past, I've already done that, using MySQL. To do that, I had to click on a tool (edit : MySQL WebSite Configuration) created by MySQL. On this tool, I was able to tell VS to upload the model on the database. I've looked up a few, and don't really get how to do this without this tool.

Please excuse my english if it's bad, I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication, Simple Membership, or something else?  What ORM are you using?

Comment: Maybe he needs the tool that generates the necessary tables in SQL Server for use with the membership provider.

Comment: @ZippyV Your answer sounds a bit like sarcasme to me. If it isn't, yes, this is what I need

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to create a custom membership provider. There is a [tutorial on how to do this here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider).  A custom membership provider will allow you to use the existing security framework in ASP.NET with a custom database you have designed.